# Getter function from defineProperty doesn't return selector

Tags: javascript, oop, object, properties, getter

I try to return a selector trough a getter function from an object, which is initialized after its creation. Why is my property "undefined"? Can't wrap my head around this...

http://jsfiddle.net/micka/fBPxG/

HTML:

```
<div class="current"></div>
```

JS:

```
var Slider = {
    init: function (config) {
        this.config = config;
        console.log('this should be the div with a class of current', this.currentSelector)
    }
};

Slider.init({
    mySelector: $('div')
});

Object.defineProperty(Slider, 'currentSelector', {
    get: function () {
        return $('.current', this.config.mySelector);
    }
});
```

Comment: The general execution direction is linearly from top-to-bottom. So you try to access the getter before it has been defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Object.defineProperty(Slider, 'currentSelector', {
get: function () {
    return $('.current', this.config.mySelector);
}
```

});

Object.defineProperty is defined after `Slider.init({...})`
When Slider.init triggered, the currentSelector attribute hasn't been defined and return undefined.

Solution:
Please move up Object.defineProperty